# Behavior vs. State Based Testing

Tags: unit-testing, mocking

I know this question is part of a bit of a religious war, but I have the following situation:
I have an object, `Responder` that calls a method on object `Updater`in response to different events.  I recently separated the testing in this way: state-based tests for the `Updater` method itself, and behavior-based tests for the `Responder` that calls it.  That is, I mock the `Updater` in the `Responder` tests, just to ensure that it is called.

Should I still be testing the state of the objects that are supposed to be updated in the `Responder` tests and not mocking the `Updater`?  I like what I have done because it requires less setup and seems to better isolate the tests.  However, this seems to tie the implementation and expected behavior of `Responder` to `Updater`.  Is that too brittle?  This is a simplified example.

Comment: What kind of tests will satisfactorily increase your comfort level that the code works?  Would an integration test suffice?

Comment: I suppose an integration test that ties it all together would increase my confidence.  However, I'd also just like to know if people think this is a valid way of testing at the unit level.

Answer (score 10):

If I did understand your question correctly you really need at least two levels of testing:

1. Unit tests, where you are trying to test only one class and mock all the dependencies (so in your case Updater needs to be mocked here). These tests help you develop the code (especially if you are using TDD), make sure the class behaves as designed and even document how this class is meant to behave. Pretty much every class should have unit tests. However, as you noticed even if you have 100% test coverage you have no guarantee that your program works or even starts up!
2. Acceptance, integration and end-to-end tests - these tests cover either the whole application or big modules and test that everything works together. In general you don't use mocks at this level (you might stub a whole module/web service though, depending on the context). These tests don't have to test every single implementation detail (and shouldn't), because this is done by unit tests. They make sure that everything is correctly wired and working together. In your case you wouldn't mock Updater here.

So to sum up I think you really need to do both to have your application properly tested.

Comment: _"Pretty much every class should have unit tests."_ Why? _"Unit tests, where you are trying to test only one class and mock all the dependencies"_ **All** the dependencies? Are you sure?

Comment: @abetteroliver in theory yes, all of them. In practice of course sometimes you would just ignore some static helpers, etc. There is always a temptation to leave a lot of these running production code, but this may make make testing all the codepaths tricky, and hence is discouraged.

Comment: If an instance of a class creates a list then you certainly would not mock it. Nor can you. If you extract some code from a class and put it into a separate class - why would you mock that dependency? The code has been inside the class before, not mocked. That and more makes _mock all the dependencies_ an interesting suggestion. Also, there are more kinds of test doubles than just mocks. And last but not least, a unit test is not restricted to a single class, if that's what you mean by _Unit tests, where you are trying to test only one class_

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what/how you are trying to test.

If you don't have any dependency in the Updater class, there is no other way than to test it's state after calling the method under test. If there is some dependency, you could test it's behavior as to what it should do (calling other methods on other classes)

The other way around could also be true for the Responder class. You could test it's state or you can test it's behavior as you did just now. Testing it's state you will likely use the real implementation of the Updater and not mock it, or use a stub in it's place that does just the minimum.

When mostly testing behavior and mocking a lot of stuff, it would be even more necessary to have acceptance (regression/integration/end-to-end) tests to back up your unit tests, just like Grzenio mentions. (It seems he is a "mockist" (behavior) tester)

When doing state based testing mostly, you use more real implementations and their interaction and the need to back those up is less relevant. But this is by no means a way to discard them entirely, it's just that you already have some regression/integration in your tests.

I think you shouldn't split the tests up too much as that might make it easier for things to fall in between the cracks.

Disclaimer: I am not a tdd guru and I don't advocate one over the other. Good info about classic vs behavior can be found on the net. Martin Fowler hasa good starting point on the subject: [Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)

I am currently reading Growing Object Oriented Software, Guided by Tests and am leaning towards the mockist side of the fence. But I think there is a small grey area on both sides.